# Frame displays the same picture

Tags: java, image, frame

My java program downloads an image from google based on latitude and longitude. The image saves to my desktop. I then call a new frame to open and view the image. Here's the error. When I try to download one image and view it it works fine, but when I try to download another image, which overrides the previous image, the frame displays the previous image instead of the new one.

```
                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+x+","+y+"&zoom=14&size=650x600&maptype=hybrid&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:X%7C"+ll.get(1)+","+ll.get(2)+"&sensor=true");
                    image = ImageIO.read(url);
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\Desktop\\locationpic.png"));
                    new classes.viewPic(); // calls pic viewer
                }catch(Exception e){print("Could not download image...",Default);}
```

Picture viewer

```
public class viewPic extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new viewPic();
    }
    public viewPic() {
        this.setTitle("Picture Viewer");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\Desktop\\locationpic.png");
        panel1.add(new JLabel(pic));
        this.add(panel1);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Since I have another frame open, a "parent" frame, setting the default close operation to exit on close would close all of my frames.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the image you download each time is different? Based on your code there is nothing wrong. Try this: download and display the image in a single program (there is a constructor for ImageIcon taking an image, give it the one you create in your first sample). That way you will know if there is some cache mechanism preventing the refresh.

Comment: My previous comment isn't very clear: Download and display the image without writing to the disk as an intermediate step. It will rule out a cache problem.

Comment: @schmop, I'm trying it now, I'll get back to you in a sec

Comment: Well @schmop it works just as planned! Might I add it is much more efficient. Thank you for your help, I will post the working code now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to force the image to be reloaded from the disk. This can be done by:

1. using `ImageIO` to read the image.
2. using the `Image.flush()` method.

as demonstrated below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ImageReload extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel timeLabel;
    JLabel imageLabel;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("timeLabel.jpg");

    public ImageReload()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        imageLabel = new JLabel( timeLabel.getText() );

        add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String imageName = "timeLabel.jpg";
                    BufferedImage image = ScreenImage.createImage(timeLabel);
                    ScreenImage.writeImage(image, imageName);

                    //  This works using ImageIO

//                  imageLabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imageName) ) ) );

                    //  Or you can flush the image

                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
                    icon.getImage().flush();
                    imageLabel.setIcon( icon );
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println( e );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ImageReload() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note:

This example uses the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class to dynamically create an image of the label as the time changes.

Answer (score 0):

I did as suggested, I passed the image right on to the image viewer, without saving it to my drive. Here's the code.

```
                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+x+","+y+"&zoom=14&size=650x600&maptype=hybrid&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:X%7C"+x+","+y+"&sensor=true");
                    image = ImageIO.read(url);
                    //ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\Desktop\\locationpic.png"));
                    new classes.viewPic(image);
                }catch(Exception e){print("Could not download image...",Default);}
```

Now the picture viewer

```
public viewPic(BufferedImage image) {
        this.setTitle("Picture Viewer");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        // ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\Desktop\\locationpic.png");
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(image);
        panel1.add(new JLabel(pic));
        this.add(panel1);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I commented out the line where it downloads the image to my desktop, instead I passed the image right on into the frame. I also deleted the 'void main' in the picture viewer code since it doesn't need to be there for any reason.

Thanks again to all who responded :) :) :) thank you